# Is it possible to create a Binance/Coinbase account programmatically?

Tags: binance, cryptocurrency

I noticed that services like advcash are albe to create a binance account automatically, but in the binance api docs I don't see anything to create accounts. The only thing would be to use sub-accounts but I it don't understand what they are and if they can be used for my purpose

[image: advcash screenshot]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binance doesn't allow creating an account through their official API. As well as Coinbase and probably all major exchanges.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you have any idea of how the could have done it?

Comment: Possibly some private API that I'm sure exchanges provide to their business partners, or maybe a simple manual registration of the account by ADVcash's employees.